# XSS attack not executing with correct payload

Tags: xss, javascript

Hello I was testing on a private program where I was able to inject XSS but for some reason it is not popping up when I put the mouse over the input field.

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="alert(document.cookie)">
```

[image: even checking Edit as HTML showing the correct code nothing has been encoded]

Note: First I created `<svg onload="alert(1)">`

Which did not work then I created the input field which was visible on the page but was not executing the script.

The response header has a following CSP header

```
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none'; img-src data: blob: http: https:; base-uri 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-randomcharacters'; report-uri https://api.redacted.com/api2/csp_report/[randomecharacters];
```

Comment: Is there any CSP on the page you're testing?

Comment: I checked the page source code there is no ContentSecurePolicy happens to be seen in meta tags
Also I have tried using <marquee> tag and it started running the whole page on the screen so the tags are perfectly working
I'm wondering if i can rather than alerting a pop up i could just demonstrate by stealing the cookies

Comment: The content-security-policy can also be part of the http headers. Have you checked that as well?

Comment: @nobody You're right there is a header with the value mentioned below:
 object-src 'none'; img-src data: blob: http: https:; base-uri 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-[randomwords]'; report-uri https://api.redacted.com/api2/csp_report/[randomwords];

Answer (score 1):

The Content Security Policy has the [`'strict-dynamic'` directive, which overrides a lot of other directives (`'self'` and `'unsafe-`*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src). With `'unsafe-inline'` being overridden, and no `'unsafe-hashes'`, inline event handlers such as you're adding are inoperative.

I expect your XSS will work if you use a browser that doesn't understand the CSP `'strict-dynamic'` directive (which, being part of CSP level 3, is newer than `'unsafe-inline'`). However, that's mostly only going to be very outdated versions of modern browsers, or Internet Explorer.

Comment: Congratulations, finally a website, which implements CSP correctly!

Comment: @MechMK1 Well, as long as your browser supports CSP3. If it only supports CSP1 or 2, unsafe-inline would make the site vulnerable anyhow.

Comment: The only "major" browser without CSP3 support is Safari. All others support CSP 3 since 2017. Furthermore, since nonces are set, browsers with CSP2 support will ignore unsafe-inline, but will allow 'self' and https. So really only, CSP 1 browsers are vulnerable, which are even older.